# Sqoop import as ORC ERROR java.io.IOException: HCat exited with status 1

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, orc

I am trying to import a table from Netezza DB using sqoop hcatlog ( see below)  in ORC format as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978522/sqoop-import-as-orc-file)

Sqoop command:

```
sqoop import
-m 1
--connect <jdbc_url>
--driver <database_driver>
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager
--username <db_username>
--password <db_password>
--table <table_name>
--hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat
--hcatalog-database <hcat_db>
--hcatalog-table < table_name >
--create-hcatalog-table
--hcatalog-storage-stanza 'stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")';
```

However , it failed with following exception. After spending few hours , I have no clue as to why it is failing. Any help / lead is much appreciated.

```
16/04/21 19:51:22 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: HCat exited with status 1
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.executeExternalHCatProgram(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:1148)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.launchHCatCli(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:1097)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.createHCatTable(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:644)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.configureHCat(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:340)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.configureImportOutputFormat(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:802)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.configureOutputFormat(ImportJobBase.java:98)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:259)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
```

**UPDATE:**
I can see that empty table was created though source table has 200k records.
Any suggestion to fix this issue ?

Comment: can you try query with `-verbose` , so that we can get more details.

Comment: Also, make sure `--hcatalog-table` does not exist as you are using `--create-hcatalog-table`

Comment: table did not exist. sqoop would've reported AlreadyExistsException if it would have existed.